# Show DialogFragment in Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use a DialogFragmemt in an adapter, but it doesn't work as planned.
I have listed the Dialog class and the adapter below.

**DialogFragment (ListsSettings.kt)**

```
class ListsSettings : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_lists_settings, container, false)      
        return view
    }
}
```

**Adapter (AllListAdapter.kt) -> (onCreateViewHolder)**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_all_lists, parent, false)

Show Fragment ->

    view.setOnLongClickListener {
        val activity = context as FragmentActivity
        val dialog = ListsSettings()
        dialog.show(activity.supportFragmentManager, "dialog")
        return@setOnLongClickListener true
    }

    return ViewHolder(view)
}
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amelie.volvic, PID: 31327
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
```

Comment: First of all, I think you should use setOnClickListener instead of setOnLongClickListener. The second point is, You should do this in onBindViewHolder and the third point is when you tap on view, get that click using the callBack function in your fragment/activity and then open dialog fragment.

Comment: First: setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener are different things, everyone should know better how their app design is. Second: Okey. Last: How?

Comment: For 3rd point, you can create an interface, which will give you a callback in your fragment/activity when you perform a tap on your view in the adapter. Then pass that interface as an argument in the constructor of your adapter. Google it, you will find plenty of examples for that.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
view.setOnLongClickListener {
    val dialog = ListsSettings()
    dialog.show(context.supportFragmentManager, "dialog")
    return@setOnLongClickListener true
}
```

if this does not work move this code to "**onBindViewHolder**"

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. 
"Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager" :/

Comment: Check @Bhavnik comment and take your click action out of adapter to Activity/Fragment where you have Recycler. Create an interface for it and add it to your Adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
view.setOnLongClickListener {
            val activity: FragmentActivity = context as FragmentActivity
            val fm: FragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            val dialog = ListsSettings()
            dialog.show(fm, "dialog")
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }
```

Comment: Not working: The Error :/ "android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity"